# Dropzone is not working in Xamarin.Form. and android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, dropzone

When you add dropzone and try to attach a photo from Android, 
I leave the app.

What should I do?

I'm using Xamarin.Form and I just called the dropzone sample screen.

It works fine in a web browser or iOS.

Help me. TT

------------------------------- sample code ------------------------------------

Dropzone simple example

This is the most minimal example of Dropzone. The upload in this example
  doesn't work, because there is no actual server to handle the file upload.

---

Comment: dropzone is a JS framework .Did you use it on webview?

Comment: Yes.. Cleared Xamarin NoHistory Field attribute or set it to false. Thanks.